# Does the series $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty -\log (1-p_j^{-3/4})$ diverge, where $\{p_j\}$ is the set of primes in increasing order?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Here, $\log$ is the natual logarithm. Is there a simple convergence test I can use? Thanks.

Comment: Since the terms of the series are all positive for large $j$, the order of the terms does not really matter.

Comment: $-\ln(1-p^{-3/4})\sim 1/p^{3/4}$ and use comparison test

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{j\geq1}-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p_{j}^{3/4}}\right)=\log\left(\prod_{j\geq1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_{j}^{3/4}}\right)^{-1}\right)\geq\log\left(\prod_{j\geq1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_{j}}\right)^{-1}\right)
 $$ and the last term diverges by [Mertens third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) or using the Euler product of zeta function for $\textrm{Re}\left(s\right)>1
 $ $$\zeta\left(s\right)=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}\right)^{-1}\underset{s\rightarrow1^{+}}{\longrightarrow}\infty.
 $$